# Antonym for the verb “subordinate”

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

I'm looking for some sort of antonym for the word subordinate, to be used in a sentence such as

> She [verb] these principles above all others.

It's being used in an academic paper, so it shouldn't be too clunky.

Comment: You could try 'holds', 'values', or 'elevates'.

Comment: I think that **elevates** and **advocates** are two good antonynms.

Answer (score 4):

You already have *above* in there, so all you're missing is a simple *put*.

> She puts these principles above all others.

Answer (score 4):

There actually is a verb ***superordinate*** that means precisely the opposite of  what ***subordinate*** means.  Here is its OED definition and citation:

> *trans*. To place in a superior order or rank. Const. *to*.
>
> - 1853 Sir W. Hamilton *Logic App.* ii. 443 ― Two notions are superordinated to a third.

However, I would not recommend *superordinated* for several reasons. It is rare. It is much too long. And I really don’t think even *subordinated* fits well in your original sentence.

Instead I recommend going with one of the one-syllable suggestions others here have given, or perhaps in a few cases, a two-syllable one if it isn’t too fancy. But you very most certainly do not need some recondite five-syllable word for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

How about "elevate?" Elegant and not clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "honoured  or "glorified " raising the subject from that of an underling to something of a higher status

Answer (score 0):

Since "subordinate" is not rock bottom, only lower priority, I think *prioritize*, *prefer*, *emphasize*, *favor* would be the proper antonyms, giving a precedence without absolute superiority.

Although in the example you gave, "above all others" would suggest this is not what you require; in this case you may choose *adhere*, *devote [self to]*, *celebrate*, *cherish*.